# Dropbox Sync API only sync within the device

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, dropbox-api

My app gives the user the possibility to download some file and I have gave the user the possibility to backup all these file in a zip on dropbox with Dropbox Sync API. It seems that everything works, in fact, when I try to restore the backup from the same app, I can see all the previous backup and can restore from any of these without issues.

However, when I go to the app folder online or by my computer, the app folder is empty. Even if I try to see my previous backup with the same app from another device I can see only the backup that I've done from that device.

What can I do to solve that issue? Sometimes it happens that a backup was even stored online but the most of times it doesn't.

Here's the code that do the backup:

```
DBFilesystem.sharedFilesystem().deletePath(mainPath.childPath("Backup del \(formatter.stringFromDate(now)).zip"), error: nil)
let file = DBFilesystem.sharedFilesystem().createFile(mainPath.childPath("Backup del \(formatter.stringFromDate(now)).zip"), error: &error)
file!.writeContentsOfFile(tempPath, shouldSteal: true, error: &error)
```

I have no error here.

Than, when I try to restore a backup I ask for the previous ones with this code:

```
self.paths = DBFilesystem.sharedFilesystem().listFolder(mainPath, error: nil) as [DBFileInfo]
```

Then, in `self.paths` I can see all the backup that I've done from the device I'm currently using but not the other ones. And I can't see even the backups online. Any idea?

Comment: One possibility is that the 'DBFilesystem' isn't being held open for long enough to actually complete the upload. (Everything is async, so the file only begins to upload once you've saved it. If it's a big file, it could certainly take time for that to complete.) Double check the lifecycle of your 'DBFilesystem' and your app and make sure there's enough time for the upload to happen. Looking at the logs from the app may also help diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Thre's no log from dropbox. How can I check my DBFileSystem lifecycle and how can I force the app to complete the upload. Even if I leave the app running for hours, small backup are not uploaded.

Comment: The Sync SDK logs quite a bit, so I'm not sure what you mean when you say "There's no log from Dropbox." In terms of the lifecycle, you'll need to look at your code and make sure the object is being retained.

Comment: The sharedFileSystem is not retained by default? And with swift code I'm using ARC so I don't think that I have to add extra code for this. 
The log only said me that there is a warning because I'm trying to delete a file that doesn't exists but nothing about the upload. After many minutes comes up message like "PUT: new offset 8388608, expected 4194304". Does it tells you something?

Comment: After about an hour I notice that a backup of 45MB was uploaded so I think that it needs just more times. But why the app needs to run for all the time?

Comment: We actually do some amount of uploading in the background (as much as is permitted on iOS), but that's as much as we can do without the app actually running.

Comment: Ok thanks! Is there a way to monitor the upload process?

Comment: Yes, you can just an add an observer on the file and then check `DBFileStatus.progress`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I will read the API in more details!